# How to do multiple call using nexmo in-app voice?

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, vonage

Hello i try to create in app voice following this tutorial https://developer.nexmo.com/client-sdk/tutorials/app-to-phone/client-sdk/app-to-phone/js-code/javascript and combine it with laravel. Can it use to make multiple call like 3 users use it at the same times? it seems like when i try to use it for multiple call at the same times the connection use the same websocket.

This my javascript code:

```
// contact button on table 1
dataTableAdminLeader.on('click', '.call-button', function(){
  $('#phone-call-modal').modal('show');
  let id                  = $(this).data('id');
  let master_number_id    = $(this).data('master_numbers_id');
  let target_number       = $(this).data('number');
  // input reset
  document.querySelector('#target-phone').value = target_number;
  document.querySelector('#master-number-id').value = master_number_id;
  document.querySelector('#id-edit').value = id;
  document.querySelector('#master-numbers-id-edit').value = master_number_id;
  // ajax object 
  const xhr               = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // all constant needed for call
  const USER_JWT          = "{{ $jwt_token }}";
  const phoneNumberInput  = document.querySelector("#cs-phone");
  const statusElement     = document.querySelector("#status-call");
  // button object selector
  const callButton        = document.querySelector(".btn-call");
  const hangupButton      = document.querySelector(".btn-hangup");
  const updateButton      = document.querySelector(".btn-update");
  const closeButton       = document.querySelector('.btn-close');
  const statusButton      = document.querySelector('.btn-status');
  // input object selector
  let campaign_result     = document.querySelector('#campaignresult');
  let note_contacted      = document.querySelector('#note_contacted');
  let note_container      = document.querySelector('.note_container');
  let campaignContainer   = document.querySelector('.campaign-container');
  // call status check
  let callStatusCompleted = false;
  let callStatusAnswered  = false;
  // reset property
  campaign_result.value   = "";
  note_container.style    = 'display: none';
  // listening to event
  campaign_result.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(campaign_result.value == 2){
      note_container.style.removeProperty('display');
      note_contacted.setAttribute('required', 'required');
    }else{
      note_container.style = 'display: none';
      note_contacted.removeAttribute('required');
    }
  });
  // nexmo status reset
  statusElement.innerText = '';
  // nexmo call button reset
  callButton.style.display = "inline";
  hangupButton.style.display = "none";
  // timeouts set
  setTimeout(() => {
    callButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }, 4000);
  // nexmo object start
  new NexmoClient({ debug: true }).login(USER_JWT).then(app => {
    callButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      let number = phoneNumberInput.value;
      if (number !== ""){
        app.callServer(number);
      } else {
        statusElement.innerText = 'Please enter your phone number.';
      }
    });
    app.on("member:call", (member, call) => {
      console.log('member:call:oke:',app);
      // object selector reset
      callButton.style.display = 'none';
      closeButton.style.display = 'none';
      hangupButton.style.removeProperty('display');
      statusButton.style.removeProperty('display');
      // event when hangup button clicked
      hangupButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        call.hangUp();
      });
    });
    app.on("call:status:changed",(call) => {
      console.log('Periodik : ', call.status);
      // animation call
      let statusAnimation = `<p class="saving">Call status: ${call.status}<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></p>`;
      // assign call animation to nexmo status display
      statusElement.innerHTML = statusAnimation;
      // filter nexmo status condition
      switch(call.status) {
        case call.CALL_STATUS.STARTED:
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.RINGING:
          // ajax params
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.FAILED:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.display = 'none';
          statusButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.CANCELLED:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.BUSY:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.TIMEOUT:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.REJECTED:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.UNANSWERED:
          callStatusAnswered = false;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          closeButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.COMPLETED:
          call.hangUp();
          callStatusCompleted = true;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.display = 'none';
          updateButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          closeButton.style.display = 'none';
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          campaignContainer.style.removeProperty('display');
          dataTableAdminLeader.ajax.reload();
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        case call.CALL_STATUS.ANSWERED:
          callStatusAnswered = true;
          callButton.style.display = 'none';
          hangupButton.style.removeProperty('display');
          closeButton.style.display = 'none';
          statusButton.style.display = 'none';
          // ajax send
          params = `id=${id}&master_number_id=${master_number_id}&status=${call.status}`;
          xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('/call/update') }}', false);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          xhr.onload = function(){
            let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('xhr: ',response);
          }
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Case call status: ', call.status);
      }
    });
  }).catch(function(){
    alert('Network Problem, refresh page and try again later. Please contact dev team if this problem not fix in few minutes.');
    console.error;
    $('#phone-call-modal').modal('hide');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple outbound phone calls consecutively using the Vonage Voice API and the Client SDK. The function, `callServer()` takes a phone number you wish to call as the argument as documented in the [Client SDK documentation](https://developer.nexmo.com/sdk/stitch/javascript/Application.html#callServer__anchor).

The code you demonstrated above receives that phone number argument from the form input: `const phoneNumberInput  = document.querySelector("#cs-phone");`. This is an input for one phone number. You would need to revise your form in your Laravel application to have multiple phone number inputs and loop through them in consecutive calls to `callServer()`.

You can also read more about the Voice API and the various parameters and their data types on the [API Reference Documentation](https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice#createCall).

Comment: Oh sorry, the "multiple" in my question mean 3 user/customer service use same route to call different number at the same times.

Comment: No worries. Yes, you can make an API call through this route multiple times consecutively. Each API call will initiate a new voice call, consecutively. There are capacity limitations as mentioned in [this guide](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/troubleshooting#capacity).

Comment: Hi while making multiple calls with js sdk how can i make sure when any one of them answers other numbers get disconnected?